# Calling function from another staticmethod function within a class

Tags: python, class, oop

I have the following code, where from `cool_function()` I'd like to call `somefunc()`

```
class MyKlass:

    # This function is to be internally called only
    def somefunc(self,text):
        return (text + "_NEW")

    @staticmethod
    def cool_function(ixdirname, ixname):
        tmp = self.somefunc(ixname)
        print ixdirname, ixname, tmp
        return


tmp = MyKlass.cool_function("FOODIR","FOO")
```

The result I want it to print out is:

```
FOODIR, FOO, FOO_NEW
```

What's the way to do it?
Currently it prints this:

```
    tmp = self.somefunc(ixname)
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: Why is `somefunc` an instance method?

Comment: so... why do you have a staticmethod at all?  Like ever in any code?  What relationship does `cool_function` bear on `MyKlass`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to do this:

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def somefunc(text):
        return text + '_NEW'
    @staticmethod
    def cool_function(ixdirname, ixname):
        tmp = MyClass.somefunc(ixname)
        print((ixdirname, ixname, tmp))
        return

MyClass.cool_function('FOODIR', 'FOO')
```

Comment: I tried it gave me this: `TypeError: unbound method somefunc() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`

Comment: @pdubois, You'd have to add the self back in the somefunc method parameter.  I've updated this answer.

Comment: @garnertb: I tried, same problem. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Yes, the both methods need to be static methods or you need to use an instance of MyClass.  The code is now correct.

Comment: Adding @staticmethod on top of `somefunc` worked. But what if I exclusively want `somefunc` to be executed within MyClass only?

Comment: @pdubois Does nesting `somefunc` under `cool_function` works out for you?

Comment: Makes sense. But ugly no? :-) No worries, the current solution is more than enough. Thanks so much...

Answer (score 2):

Call it with class.method, for example:

```
tmp = MyKlass.somefunc(ixname)
```